# Disabling the button in React JS

Tags: reactjs, button

Here is the code to disable the button. I do not understand why the button is not disabled. Please help me find where it went wrong.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  const handleDisable = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h3> Disable Button</h3>
      <input type='text' onChange={handleDisable} value={value} />
      <button disabled={value.length < 1}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Your code is working https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-silence-rr4k3?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

try checking for  <button disabled={value.length === 0}>

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, guys for your comments. After spending bloody many hours, I found that it is not working on Safari.